# Достаточно ли изучить 1 книгу по Java Core что бы перейти к Spring Framework?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Я начал изучение Java с книги ***"Герберт Шилдт - Полное руководство, 10 издание"***, затем я думаю изучить ***"Кея Хорстманна Библиотека профессионала, том 1 и 2(до главы с JDBC)"***, немного порешать задачи на ***Codewars***, так же, изучить книгу и курс на Stepike по SQL, после этого можно уже брать книгу ***"Spring в действии 6 издание"*** и после первой и четырех глав, начать писать что-то свое на Spring?

Comment: Я бы посоветов прочитать Философию Java и только потом к Spring

Comment: Просто берите и изучайте. Тут вам никто не скажет точно, достаточно ли вы уже знаете или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нет,не достаточно. В Spring используется многое из j2ee парадигмы, а Шилдт  описывает стандартные подходы. Сначала поимите как работает контейнер (надеюсь
вы не будете писать свой собственный со своей спецификацией), посмотрите что такое JTA, узнайте JDBC, прочувствуйте @ManageBean, напишите пару -тройку аннотоций. И тогда Вам spring может быть будет полезен.

Comment: Чтобы успешно использовать Spring необязательно все это знать. При желании это можно изучить в процессе или после спринга, но это не обязательное требование.